# Usage of SDO_POINT from Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-spatial

I am working with Oracle Spatials and I have the following query:

The SDO_GEOMETRY if made of five constituent data:

CREATE TYPE sdo_geometry AS OBJECT ( SDO_GTYPE NUMBER, SDO_SRID NUMBER, SDO_POINT SDO_POINT_TYPE, SDO_ELEM_INFO SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY, SDO_ORDINATES SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY);

Once I query the database to get the resultSet - how do I get to the costituent data from the above object.

I am basically interested in getting the x and y coordinates from the SDO_POINT so as to be able to update the values in another POJO Class.

I did go through the JGeometry option from:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14373/oracle/spatial/geometry/JGeometry.html

but I am  probably missing something and I am not able to use it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `JGeometry` class is contained in sdoapi.jar. In my install, I found it in /apps/oracle/product/102040/md/lib/. The `102040` part may differ for you.

Get the SDO_Geometry out of the result set, and then load it, like so:

```
STRUCT struct = (STRUCT) resultSet.getObject(resultSetIndex);
JGeometry jGeo = JGeometry.load(struct);
```

You can then get the information you need right out of that object. Depending on the contents, you may be able to use `getPoint()` or you may need to use `getType()`, `getElemInfo()`, `getOrdinatesArray()`, etc.

Comment: Many thanks Chris. I havent gotten hold of the jar yet. But what I would like to know is can I iterate through the jGeo to get the longitude and latitude and then set it in another POJO.

Comment: thanks Chris, I have the latitude and longitude fetched from the getPoint() method.  Your help is much appreciated. Cheers